# return value of gets command

Tags: file, tcl, tclsh

what does the return value of `gets` command in following exercise means?

I tried to read `file` by `tclsh` on command line.

### File

```
           10      2       12      1       13
1       2       3       4       5        6
1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4a       5
```

### Command & Output (command-line)

```
% set fp [open file r]
file4
% gets $fp line
45
%  gets $fp line
42
%  gets $fp line
41
%  gets $fp line
42
%  gets $fp line
-1
% close $fp
```

when I got `-1` output I closed the file-pointer `$fp`. but what does the values `45 42 41 42` meant?

Comment: I noticed you tagged a few questions with [tag:tcsh] which weren't actually *about* `tcsh` (on this site, and at unix.stachexchange.com). You should tag questions with the [tag:tcsh] tag **only** if the question is actually *about* `tcsh`, not if this happens to be the shell you're using. Thanks :-)

Comment: will take care about it in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/gets.htm) page of `gets` command

> Syntax :
>
> gets channelId ?varName?
>
> This command reads the next line from channelId, returns everything in
>   the line up to (but not including) the end-of-line character(s), and
>   discards the end-of-line character(s).
>
> If varName is specified and an empty string is returned in varName
>   because of end-of-file or because of insufficient data in nonblocking
>   mode, then the return count is -1.
>
> If varName is omitted the line is returned as the result of the
>   command. If varName is specified then the line is placed in the
>   variable by that name and the return value is a count of the number of
>   characters returned.

**As you can see from the man page, it returns the count of characters which is read by `gets` command in one single line.**
In the first line of the file, it read 45 characters and returned 45 as a result and the string value will be stored in the variable `line` as per your code.

This is repeated for all lines and will return -1 once the `eof` reached for that file.

Comment: The `-1` can be returned in other cases too, most notably when reading from a non-blocking channel that doesn't have a full line available (and `fblocked` can be used to detect this).